# Spring Kafka Always rebalance after 5 min even i pause consumer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

there is a Time-consuming operation (about 10 min) ,but kafka aways rebalance after  5 min,even i pause the consumer. the consumer method :

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = {TopicAppoint.EXECUTE_SCHOOL_DATA_STATICS_TASK})
public void receiveMessage(@Payload String payload, Consumer<String, String> consumer) {

    Set<TopicPartition> assignment = consumer.assignment();
    consumer.pause(assignment);

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(payload)) {
        SchoolStatisticsTaskDTO staticsTaskDTO = JSONObject.parseObject(payload, SchoolStatisticsTaskDTO.class);
        Optional<SchoolStatisticsTaskDO> taskOptional = schoolStatisticsTaskRepository.findById(staticsTaskDTO.getTrackId());
        taskOptional.ifPresent(schoolStaticsTaskDO -> {
            // handler
        });
    }

    consumer.resume(assignment);
}
```

this is my config:

```
  kafka:
bootstrap-servers: 192.168.0.230:9092
producer:
  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  retries: 3
  properties:
    max.request.size: 12582912
consumer:
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  group-id: dc-fitness-data-consumer-group
  properties:
    max.partition.fetch.bytes: 12582912
  #enable-auto-commit: false
listener:
  ack-mode: record
  concurrency: 6
```

**LOGS**

```
  13:09:20.219 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-25, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
   13:09:20.219 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-25, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-4, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-5, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-2, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-3, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-0, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-1]
   13:09:20.219 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-4, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-5, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-2, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-3, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-0, ft.es.records.incremental.update.task-1]
  13:09:20.219 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-25, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.220 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-2-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-21, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-2-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-21, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.student.batch.upload.task-17, ft.student.batch.upload.task-14, ft.student.batch.upload.task-13, ft.student.batch.upload.task-16, ft.student.batch.upload.task-15, ft.student.batch.upload.task-12]
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-2-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.student.batch.upload.task-17, ft.student.batch.upload.task-14, ft.student.batch.upload.task-13, ft.student.batch.upload.task-16, ft.student.batch.upload.task-15, ft.student.batch.upload.task-12]
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-2-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-21, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#8-5-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-18, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#8-5-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-18, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.record.batch.upload.task-32, ft.record.batch.upload.task-31, ft.record.batch.upload.task-34, ft.record.batch.upload.task-33, ft.record.batch.upload.task-30, ft.record.batch.upload.task-35]
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#8-5-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.record.batch.upload.task-32, ft.record.batch.upload.task-31, ft.record.batch.upload.task-34, ft.record.batch.upload.task-33, ft.record.batch.upload.task-30, ft.record.batch.upload.task-35]
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#8-5-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-18, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.class.batch.upload.task-18, ft.class.batch.upload.task-19, ft.class.batch.upload.task-20, ft.class.batch.upload.task-21, ft.class.batch.upload.task-22, ft.class.batch.upload.task-23]
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-53, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.221 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-52, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.class.batch.upload.task-26, ft.class.batch.upload.task-27, ft.class.batch.upload.task-28, ft.class.batch.upload.task-29, ft.class.batch.upload.task-24, ft.class.batch.upload.task-25]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-3-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.class.batch.upload.task-18, ft.class.batch.upload.task-19, ft.class.batch.upload.task-20, ft.class.batch.upload.task-21, ft.class.batch.upload.task-22, ft.class.batch.upload.task-23]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-53, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-26, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-27, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-28, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-29, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-24, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-25]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-4-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.class.batch.upload.task-26, ft.class.batch.upload.task-27, ft.class.batch.upload.task-28, ft.class.batch.upload.task-29, ft.class.batch.upload.task-24, ft.class.batch.upload.task-25]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-26, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-27, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-28, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-29, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-24, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-25]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#6-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-53, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-52, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-22, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-23, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-18, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-19, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-20, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-21]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: [ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-22, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-23, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-18, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-19, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-20, ft.es.class.incremental.update.task-21]
  13:09:20.223 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-4-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-47, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
  13:09:20.225 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-52, groupId=dc-fitness-data-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
```

Comment: which version for spring kafka?

Comment: kafka version : 2.12

Comment: can you post the re balancing logs

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much useful logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets look at the documentation for a while, begin with `pause()` method

**public void pause(Collection partitions)** [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

**So from the above description `pause()` method will suspend the partition from fetching the messages but it will not pause the consumer thread, which means consumer thread will do the subsequent `poll()` request to paused partitions but will not fetch any records**

**In your application :** partitions are paused but consumer thread is busy in executing Time consuming operations for more that 10 minutes without doing any poll request.

**Detecting Consumer Failures :** so when poll stops heartbeat will not sent to the cluster

> After subscribing to a set of topics, the consumer will automatically join the group when poll(long) is invoked. The poll API is designed to ensure consumer liveness. As long as you continue to call poll, the consumer will stay in the group and continue to receive messages from the partitions it was assigned. Underneath the covers, the poll API sends periodic heartbeats to the server; **when you stop calling poll (perhaps because an exception was thrown), then no heartbeats will be sent.** If a period of the configured session timeout elapses before the server has received a heartbeat, then the consumer will be kicked out of the group and its partitions will be reassigned.

**Solution :** increase the timeouts for below properties since default time is 5 minutes you are seeing rebalancing for every 5 minutes (personally will not support increasing timeouts) [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

> The new Java Consumer now supports heartbeating from a background thread. There is a new configuration `max.poll.interval.ms` which controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer will proactively leave the group (5 minutes by default). The value of the configuration `request.timeout.ms` must always be larger than max.poll.interval.ms because this is the maximum time that a JoinGroup request can block on the server while the consumer is rebalancing, so we have changed its default value to just above 5 minutes. Finally, the default value of session.timeout.ms has been adjusted down to 10 seconds, and the default value of `max.poll.records` has been changed to 500.

**Solution 2:** if you need to process huge data with less amount of time increase more partition and consume each partition with each thread (which means more concurrency), less data that can be processed in 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved this problem by adjusting the max.poll.interval.ms property.